# Load remote index.html with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I want to render a remote HTML page when my Cordova app starts, instead of "./index.html"

Tried this in config.xml

```
<content src="http://example.com/index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

And also tried placing this into ./index.html

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com/index.html';
```

Both load a blank white screen when I start the app. Got no errors in the device log. Using Cordova version 5.3.3.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you install the whitelist plugin? `<content src="http://example.com/index.html" />`should be enough. Which cordova android version do you use? Try updating to latest cordova CLI and cordova android

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `<access origin="*" />` you need to add this meta tag to your html page(s) in your cordova app:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="*">
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html page, you can write `windows.onload() function` inside this write redirect to this http://example.com/index.html

Comment: How is that different from the redirect I explained in my question?

Comment: What do you do in the onload callback to load the index.html served from your server?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `loadUrl` statement in the native code e.g. in Android, you need to find `MainActivity.java` under `platforms/android/src...`.

I myself am currently looking for a way to do this from `index.html` (to display for e.g. a loading screen / error message in case of network issues).

I believe I had tried using `window.location.href` but that simply opened the browser to the specified URL. I want it to open up in the app's WebView of course.